# Options for creating styled nested grids/boxes

Tags: html, css, nested, grid

I am looking for ideas for ways that I can best create nested boxes as shown in the image below. Ideally I would like to do this in HTML with CSS but I can also leverage a framework like bootstrap or similar for styling.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXdMl.jpg

I would like to also be able to link to other pages as a user clicks on the label within each box for additional details on a separate page.

I have basic HTML/CSS experience.

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the CSS Grid spec - see nested example:

https://gridbyexample.com/examples/example21/

Or using flexbox (which is how Bootstrap do it) see:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#nesting

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to these. I will take a look. I also want to try to automate the HTML generation from an excel/csv file so that I can regenerate when things change. (sorry that wasn't part of the original question, just a FYI.)